# Error when graphing exponential function in pgfplots: Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I'm attempting to graph the following function:

y = 0.00001096897 + 0.0003330018 * e ^ (−2.521376 * x)

However, I keep getting the error message:

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '0.00001096897 + 0.0003330018 * 2.718 ^ (−2.521376 * x)').
```

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} \usepackage{pgfplotstable} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!] \centering \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height = 20em,
    draw = none]
    \addplot[blue, smooth]{0.00001096897 + 0.0003330018 * 2.718 ^ (−2.521376 * x)}; \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture} \label{fig:repeatgraph} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have nonstandard characters in your code.

Comment: @marmot Which characters are nonstandard? Is it the `^` symbol? If so, how should a power be presented?

Comment: The minus in front of `2.521376` is not a standard minus. Replace it by a real minus. You can also use `0.00001096897 + 0.0003330018 * exp (-2.521376 * x)`. Copy this literally, without replacing the minus by a nonstandard character.

Comment: In laymans terms, use ascii chars for this. The minus is probably a unicode char which is not handled by the pgf math engine

Comment: @daleif IMO, its already a specalised term `;-)`.

Comment: @Raaja a lot of people does not know what "nonstandard characters" mean. Just see all those examples with invisible unicode chars that no-one knows where came from

Comment: @daleif Once I was revising a manuscript, which had all such unicode characters, I was baffled for quite some time, why it was happening. Then only to find out that it was a happening due to sloppy cut-copy-pasting from pdf's --> resulted in a completely rewriting the article :D

Comment: @Raaja try looking up the unicode char `greek question mark`, then consider all the programming languages  that uses the similar ascii char.

Comment: Huhh okay, I will try-it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Finding the non-ascii characters is the hard part. If you have them, you can (re)define them using DeclareUnicodeCharacter:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
      width=\textwidth,
      height = 20em,
      draw = none]
    \addplot[blue, smooth]{0.00001096897 + 0.0003330018 * 2.718 ^ (−2.521376 * x)}; \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture} \label{fig:repeatgraph}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```